# How to run a statement exactly once in recursion function

Tags: python

I want to make a copy of list in recursion function

```
def rec(I: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    new_lst = I[:] # <- want to do this only on first call of rec in recursive stack
    # ....(new_lst is edited)

    rec(new_lst)
    return new_lst
```

Comment: could you not simply *pass* a copy of the list to the function and avoid any need to copy it within the function?  from outside, `rec(some_list[:])`.

Comment: What do you mean by "runs only once"? What does the `rec()` function do? And why does it need to be recursive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to wrap it in an initializer function, then call that initializer function instead:

```
def rec(I: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    ....(new_lst is edited)

    rec(new_lst)
    return new_lst

def startrec(I: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return rec(I[:])
```

Answer (score 3):

we can add one more parameter.

```py
def rec(I: List[int], is_first: bool) -> List[int]:
    if is_first:
        new_lst = I[:] 
    # edit new list
    # then
    rec(new_lst, False)
    return new_lst


# call function 
rec(some_list, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to keep your original function `rec`, but add a new function that rec redefines itself as. So whatever statement is in `rec` will be run exactly once.

```py
def rec(I: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    new_lst = I[:] # only happens on the first call
    rec = _rec # redefine the rec function so the next time it gets called, we call _rec


def _rec(I: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    # ....(new_lst is edited)

    rec(new_lst)
    return new_lst
```